# SSD wear for rMBP mid 2015 15" with running VMware Fusion

Tags: ssd, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have the rMBP mid 2015 15" with a 512GB SSD. I will be running VMware Fusion for my Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and Redhat virtual machines.

Most of the time I will be using my Windows 8.1 virtual guest and will use the other virtual guest as needed. I am concerned I am going to prematurely wear our my SSD with running a virtual machines pretty much everyday on a SSD.

I am busy going through a lengthy wikipedia on SSD wear but everything is very vague. Does anybody have experience with a similar usage case and with fairly recent hardware?

Comment: "I am concerned I am going to prematurely wear our my SSD"  You're concerned over nothing. See this SU blog post for some tips: [Maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/).

Comment: Also see these related/duplicate SU question/answers for some good info: [What is the lifespan of an SSD drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/39719/what-is-the-lifespan-of-an-ssd-drive), [Do SSDs really have a much shorter life than HDDs?](http://superuser.com/questions/278750/do-ssds-really-have-a-much-shorter-life-than-hdds?lq=1), [HDD vs SSD durability](http://superuser.com/questions/218343/hdd-vs-ssd-durability)

Comment: Thanks for the links. However you took my comment out of context. I am not concerned with SSD lifespan under normal usage. My concerns comes from having a previous SSD fail after about 3 years only. What bugged me I could never figure out if it was because of the cheap brand/model or because of the operating system virtualisation.

Answer (score 1):

I have several VMs that I have been running for years on SSDs (a mixture of Windows, Linux and OS X) with no troubles or failures (Mac Pro tower).

I don't see why running a VM on an SSD is any more intensive than running the OS on it directly.

If it's truly a concern for you (and I don't think it should be), then you can get an external SSD and connect it via Thunderbolt.