# Is a junction point effective in decreasing write cycles of SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, junction

Since SSDs have a limited life cycle and I have one experience of an SSD crash, I decided to be proactive and avoid writes.

I moved all my data to an HDD.

I understood from various people that indexing does a lot of writes.  I know that Adobe Premiere also does.

So I moved my Programdata folder and Users folder to an HDD from my SSD.  (Used robocopy from resuce disk cmd).  All is well.

So, **when windows sees a junction point will data be written directly to the destination (HDD) or will it be first written to the SSD and then another process will write it to the HDD?**

I feel it will directly go to D Drive, still wanted to confirm.

Comment: Not an answer but:  You're paranoid dude. :) You're not going to "write" your SSD to death in your lifetime.  The fact that you had an SSD fail has nothing to do with how much you wrote to it.  you're making an assumption based on bad information (that SSDs have a write cycle limit you could hit in it's lifetime).  See: http://superuser.com/questions/218343/hdd-vs-ssd-durability

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a junction in NTFS as a wormhole. Any read or write instructions through that point will be redirected to the true location at the other end.

So there may be a very small amount of activity from the SSD where it looks up the correct end point but that's it.